# Presenting hierarchical data with different conditions in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables. In one table my raw data and in other table the relationships as below

```
Declare @Emp table(EmpId int,EmpName Varchar(100),CITY VARCHAR(100),Designation Varchar(100),ReportingManager Int)
INSERT INTO @Emp
VALUES(1,'Ram','Hyderabad','TL',6)
,(2,'Laxman','Hyderabad','TL',9)
,(3,'Suresh','Bangalore','Officer',6)
,(4,'Rajesh','Bangalore','Officer',9)
,(5,'Lokesh','Delhi','TL',6)
,(6,'Venkatesh','Mumbai','Manager',6)
,(7,'Subbu','Patna','Officer',9)
,(8,'Ravi','Hyderabad','Officer',9)
,(9,'Sai','Hyderabad','Manager',9)
,(10,'Satish','Hyderabad','Officer',6)

DECLARE @EmpRelation TABLE(EmpRelationShipID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,ReportingTo INT,EmpID INT)
INSERT INTO @EmpRelation
VALUES(1,6)
,(2,9)
,(3,1)
,(4,5)
,(5,6)
,(7,2)
,(8,5)
,(10,1)
```

- Here the ReportingManager Column in @Emp table indicates that If Emp reports TL, then the TL's ManagerName
- Here ReportingTo Column in @EmpRelation indicates to whom he is reporting.(TL or Manager)
- Officers reports to TLs and TLs reports to Managers.

I want the data as below

```
[EMPID],[EMPNAME],[CITY],[IsManager],[HasSubordinates],[IsSubordinate],[ManagerCity],[SubordinatesList]
```

- Here [IsManager] field is that if an Employee is Manager then it is "Yes" else "No". In @Emp table "Sai" is Manager so for him this is Yes.
- [HasSubordinates] if an Employee has some employees working under him then "Yes" else "No". In this case for TLs and Managers this column is Yes
- [IsSubordinate] means if an employee reports to anybody then it is Yes in this case TL's and officers having Yes
- [ManagerCity] Suppose if an employee reports to TL then his TLs Managers city
- [SubordinatesList] The employees working under TL/Manager. For officers it is blank

I couldn't fetch the correct data. Could anyone please look into this and suggest me the query for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example should give you some ideas. It does not walk the hierarchy, i.e. using a recursive CTE, since there didn't appear to be a result that depended on checking more than one level up or down the hierarchy.

```
select E.EmpId, E.EmpName, E.City, E.Designation,
  -- Anyone who reports to themselves is a manager.
  case when E.EmpId = E.ReportingManager then 'Yes' else 'No' end as IsManager,
  -- Anyone with a related employee reporting to them has subordinates.
  case when exists ( select 42 from @EmpRelation as iER where iER.ReportingTo = E.EmpId )
    then 'Yes' else 'No' end as HasSubordinates,
  -- Anyone who reports to an employee is a subordinate.  (Should this exclude reporting to themselves?)
  case when exists ( select 42 from @EmpRelation as iER where iER.EmpId = E.EmpId )
    then 'Yes' else 'No' end as IsSubordinate,
  -- The city of the reporting manager, if any.
  ME.City as ManagerCity,
  -- A comma-delimited list of employees who report directly to the current employee.
  --   Modern versions of SQL Server could use   String_Agg .
  Stuff( (
    select ',' + sE.EmpName
      from @Emp as sE inner join @EmpRelation as sER on sER.EmpId = se.EmpId
      where sER.ReportingTo = E.EmpId
      order by sE.EmpName for XML path(''), type).value('.[1]', 'VarChar(max)' ),
    1, 1, '' ) as SubordinatesList
  from @Emp as E left outer join
    @Emp as ME on ME.EmpId = E.ReportingManager;
```

*Thank you for supplying usable sample data.*

---

Per the OP's comment, the `@EmpRelation` table is a little perplexing. `@EmpRelation` has `(3,1)` and `(10,1)` as `(ReportingTo,EmpId)`. That doesn't mean `EmpId` `1` is `ReportingTo` `3` and `10` (otherwise known as *matrix management*). Revising the query to flip the relationship requires minor changes to `HasSubordinates`, `IsSubordinate` and `SubordinateList`:

```
select E.EmpId, E.EmpName, E.City, E.Designation,
  -- Anyone who reports to themselves is a manager.
  case when E.EmpId = E.ReportingManager then 'Yes' else 'No' end as IsManager,
  -- Anyone with a related employee reporting to them has subordinates.
  case when exists ( select 42 from @EmpRelation as iER where iER.EmpId = E.EmpId )
    then 'Yes' else 'No' end as HasSubordinates,
  -- Anyone who reports to an employee is a subordinate.  (Should this exclude reporting to themselves?)
  case when exists ( select 42 from @EmpRelation as iER where iER.ReportingTo = E.EmpId )
    then 'Yes' else 'No' end as IsSubordinate,
  -- The city of the reporting manager, if any.
  ME.City as ManagerCity,
  -- A comma-delimited list of employees who report directly to the current employee.
  --   Modern versions of SQL Server could use   String_Agg .
  Stuff( (
    select ',' + sE.EmpName
      from @Emp as sE inner join @EmpRelation as sER on sER.ReportingTo = se.EmpId
      where sER.EmpId = E.EmpId
      order by sE.EmpName for XML path(''), type).value('.[1]', 'VarChar(max)' ),
    1, 1, '' ) as SubordinatesList
  from @Emp as E left outer join
    @Emp as ME on ME.EmpId = E.ReportingManager;
```

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for your effort and for giving reply.
Here the field [HasSubordinates] giving wrong result. This column is "If an Employee has anybody working under him then it is "Yes". In this case only TL's and Managers will have "Yes". But the EmpID 3 is "Officer" for him this should be "No". Could you please look into this.

Comment: [SubordinateList] colmn also wrong. This column indicates the employees working under him.In this case Under Employee "Ram" two employees are working if we see the @EmpRelation table (Employees 3 and 10 are working under EmployeeID 1)

Comment: @sasibhushan - I updated the answer to include a query with modified `where` clauses to flip the subordinate relationship.